# LINK: fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'mingw32.lib' when install scikits.bvp_solver module for python

Tags: python, gcc, mingw, solver, scikits

I tried to install `scikits.bvp_solver` on my laptop (windows 10) follow instruction here: "`pythonhosted.org/scikits.bvp_solver`"

I used `gcc-4.8.2-32` but when I perform the command: "`python setup.py config --compiler=mingw32 build --compiler=mingw32 install`", it just fails with exit status 1 (See Attachment-1 below).

Then, I make an other try with pip using: "`pip install scikits.bvp_solver`" it gets the other error that: fail with status 1181 (LINK: fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '`mingw32.lib`' ) (see Attachemnt-2), could any one give me advise for this case.

[Attachment-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsmKt.png)

[Attachment-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6qY8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `*\VC\Bin\link.exe` from your $PATH because you used msvc linker not mingw32.

Comment: Thank so much, but I think in the first case (att-1) the gcc-4.8.2 have been already used instead of msvc and it still error and "exit status 1". Could you have other advise,

Comment: By the way, I installed two version of gcc is 4.8.2 and 6.1.0, so, i found that with command "python setup.py config --compiler=mingw32 build --compiler=mingw32 install" the version 4.8.2 is seem to be called automatically. In case i would like to change to 6.1.0 during calling, what should I do?

Comment: Change your $PATH configuration.Replace gcc4.x with 6.x